# Why does masking a negative number produce a positive number?

Tags: c++, bit, bitmask

in c++, I have the following code:

```
int x = -3;
x &= 0xffff;
cout << x;
```

This produces

```
65533
```

But if I remove the negative, so I have this:

```
int x = 3;
x &= 0xffff;
cout << x;
```

I  simply get `3` as a result

Why does the first result not produce a negative number? I would expect that -3 would be sign extended to 16 bits, which should still give a twos complement negative number, considering all those extended bits would be 1. Consequently the most significant bit would be 1 too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your system uses 32-bit `int`s with two's complement representation of negatives.

Constant `0xFFFF` covers the least significant two bytes, with the upper two bytes are zero.

The value of `-3` is `0xFFFFFFFD`, so masking it with `0x0000FFFF` you get `0x0000FFFD`, or `65533` in decimal.

Positive `3` is `0x00000003`, so masking with `0x0000FFFF` gives you `3` back.

You would get the result that you expect if you specify 16-bit data type, e.g.

```
int16_t x = -3;
x &= 0xffff;
cout << x;
```

Comment: could you explain why 0xFFFD is no longer in two's complement form?

Comment: @Dillydill123 because the upper 2 bytes of 0xffff are 0. Try use a 32bit mask (i.e. 0xffffffff) and it should preserve the sign.

Comment: "The value of -3" --> "The representation of -3"

Comment: The last snippet is implementation-defined on a 32-bit int system (out-of-range assignment, 65533 to `int16_t`)

Answer (score 0):

In your case int is more than 2 bytes. You probably run on modern CPU where usually these days integer is 4 bytes (or 32 bits)

If you take a look the way system stores negative numbers you will see that its a complementary number. And if you take only last 2 bytes as your mask is 0xFFFF then you will get only a part of it.

your 2 options:

1. use short intstead of int. Usually its a half of integer and will be only 2 bites
2. use bigger mask like 0xFFFFFFFF that it covers all the bits of your integer

NOTE: I use "usually" because the amount of bits in your int and short depends on your CPU and compiler.